# use vestal versions to access object with version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vestal-versions

I am using vestal version to try and compare two versions of the same model.  In order to do this. I need to access the two instances of the model i am trying to compare.  I have tried the following code:

```
@schedule = Schedule.last

@latest_version_model = @schedule.versions.last
@2nd_to_latest_version_of_model = @latest_version_model-1
```

I know this is wrong.  @latest_version_model returns the number version, not the actual object.  @ 2nd_to_latest_version_of_model returns an error.  How do I access the latest version of the model instance and the 2nd latest version of the model instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `last` could take an argument. If you call `last(2)` you get the 2 latest elements, so doing `last(2).first` you will get the second latest element.

```
@schedule = Schedule.last

@latest_version_model = @schedule.versions.last
@2nd_to_latest_version_of_model = @schedule.versions.last(2).first
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me this type of object: 'VestalVersions::Version'.  How do i get the schedule that that corresponds to.

Comment: We got it from `@schedule`, so you already have it, don't you? Anyway it `@2nd_to_latest_version_of_model.schedule` should work.